# SonataAdminBundle show view with tabs

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm using  SontaAdminBundle and I want to organise my show action on tabs.

```
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->tab('Infos personnelles')
            ->with('Beneficiary', array('class' => 'col-lg-6'))
                ->add('email')
                ->add('firstname')
                ->add('lastname')
                ->add('civility')
                ->add('dateOfBirth')
                ->add('enabled')
                ->add('address')
            ->end()
        ->end()
        ->tab('projects')
            ->with('projects')
                ->add('title')
                ->add('statusLabel')
            ->end()
        ->end();
}
```

But It doesn't work. Is there another config to do.

Thx

Comment: Why do you use ShowMapper instead of FormMapper? Is it your redefined FormMapper?

Comment: ShowMapper used for the show action and FormMapper for create/edit actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config you used is good, you just need to update your version of sonata to master, check the changes in this commit:

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/commit/fd1a1596f86bfb4afdafe9767efaa4c787bba6a5

where the `SonataAdminBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/base_show.html.twig` was updated.

Hope this helps.